# R - web scraping through multiple URLs? with rvest and purrr

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I am trying to scrape football(soccer) statistics for a project i'm working on and i'm trying to utilise rvest and purrr to loop through the numeric values at the end of the url. I'm not sure what i'm missing but i have a snippet of the code as well as the error message that keeps coming up.

```
library(xml2)

library(rvest)

library(purrr) 

wins_URL <- "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/wins?se=%d"

map_df(1:15, function(i){

  cat(".")
  page <- read_html(sprintf(wins_URL, i))

  data.frame(statTable = html_table(html_nodes(page,"td , th")))

}) -> WinsTable
```

> Error in doc_namespaces(doc) : external pointer is not valid

I've only recently started using R so I'm no expert and would just like to know what mistakes I'm making

Comment: One challenge you are facing is that the wins table is dynamically generated through a Javascript. This means that rvest and xml2 will capture a webpage in a state prior to the moment that the table is created. You might need to recur to PhantomJS or RSelenium if you want to scrap this in R.

Comment: thank you! would it help to find a different website that has the table in an html format?

Comment: thank you! would it help to find a different website that has the table in an html format?

Comment: It would, yes. Now, the table is eventually formated in html format. But it is created some time -miliseconds- after the browser loads it. That is why rvest alone is not able to capture it, because the html rvest sees has no table yet.