# r rvest error: "Error in doc_namespaces(doc) : external pointer is not valid"

Tags: r, error-handling, rvest, purrr, xml2

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159150/r-web-scraping-through-multiple-urls-with-rvest-and-purrr), but the latter did not receive an answer I can work with. I am scraping thousands of urls with `xml2::read_html`. This works fine. But when I try and parse the resulting html documents using `purrr::map_df` and `html_nodes`, I get the following error:

```
Error in doc_namespaces(doc) : external pointer is not valid
```

For some reason, I am unable to reproduce the error using examples. The example below is not good, because it works totally fine. But if someone could explain me conceptually what the error means and how to solve it, that would be great (here is a [github thread](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.apply/issues/4) on a similar problem, but I don't follow all the technicalities).

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
urls_test <- list("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Barcelona",
             "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome")
h <- urls_test %>% map(~{
  Sys.sleep(sample(seq(1, 3, by=0.001), 1))
  read_html(.x)})
out <- h %>% map_df(~{
  a <- html_nodes(., "#firstHeading") %>% html_text()
  a <- if (length(a) == 0) NA else a
  b <- html_nodes(., ".toctext") %>% html_text()
  b <- if (length(b) == 0) NA else b

  df <- tibble(a, b)
})
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Devuan GNU/Linux ascii
```

Comment: Seems to happen when read_html() is working from a saved environment. I solved by reading the data fresh. https://community.rstudio.com/t/help-with-error-in-doc-namespaces-doc-external-pointer-is-not-valid/38868

Comment: @NBK I faced the same problem and found some (not perfect, but working) solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031325/using-rvest-with-drake-external-pointer-is-not-valid-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that R stores xml in the memory with external pointers. These external pointers are not stored in `.rds` files. So once you save the project and reopen it you will get the error `external pointer is not valid`.

Workaround:
use `xml2::write_html()` to save the parsed html to a html file. If you want to use it later just read it with `xml2::read_html()`

See also more information [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/181#issuecomment-395064636) and for parallel processing [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html#Non-exportable%20objects) and [Parallel processing XML nodes with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810140/parallel-processing-xml-nodes-with-r#55843269)