# Using rvest with drake: external pointer is not valid error

Tags: rvest, drake-r-package

When I first run the code below, everything is ok. But when I change something in `html_file %>%...` comand, for example commenting `tolower()`, I get the following error:

```
Error: target title failed.
diagnose(title)error$message:
  external pointer is not valid
diagnose(title)error$calls:
   1. └─html_file %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_text()
```

Code:

```
library(rvest)
library(drake)

some_string <- '
  <div class="main">
      <h2>A</h2>
      <div class="route">X</div>
  </div> 
'

html_file <- read_html(some_string)
title <- html_file %>% 
  html_nodes("h2") %>% 
  html_text()

plan <- drake_plan(
  html_file = read_html(some_string),
  title = html_file %>% 
    html_nodes("h2") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    tolower()
)

make(plan)
```

I found two possible solutions but I'm not enthusiastic about them.
 1. Join both steps in `drake_plan` into one.
 2. Use `xml2::write_html()` and `xml2::read_html()` as suggested [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/181#issuecomment-395064636).
Is there a better way to solve it? 
P.S. Issue was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261745/r-rvest-error-error-in-doc-namespacesdoc-external-pointer-is-not-valid), [Rstudio forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/help-with-error-in-doc-namespaces-doc-external-pointer-is-not-valid/38868), and on [github](https://github.com/bnosac/udpipe/issues/5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `drake` saves targets as RDS files (other options [here](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/plans.html#special-data-formats-for-targets)). So https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/181#issuecomment-395064636, which you brought up, is exactly the problem. I like (1) because text is compatible with RDS. Speaking broadly, it is up to the user to choose good targets compatible with `drake`'s data storage system. See https://books.ropensci.org/drake/plans.html#how-to-choose-good-targets for a discussion and links to similar issues. But you want to go with (2), you could return the file path to your HTML file from within a [dynamic file](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/plans.html#dynamic-files).