# "Error in xml_ns.xml_document(x) : external pointer is not valid"

Tags: r, powerpoint, reporting, officer

I'm using the officer package to automate powerpoint reporting but I am encountering the below error:

```
"Error in xml_ns.xml_document(x) : external pointer is not valid"
```

when I try to run the code below. Essentially I am trying to bold the word "specifically:" in line 4 of the code below. But when I run it I get that error message. I searched online and it seems to happen within other use cases such as this: [Using rvest with drake: external pointer is not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031325/using-rvest-with-drake-external-pointer-is-not-valid-error)

but I don't really understand how to incorporate their code chunk. Can anyone help?

#these 3 lines below create formatting such as bold, font size etc.

```
p_normal <- fp_text(font.size = 24)
fp_bold <- update(fp_normal, bold = TRUE) #created the bold option
fp_red <- update(fp_normal, color = "red") 

#this line creates an object with the bold option incorporated
studyobjective1 <- block_list(fpar(ftext("Specifically:", fp_bold)),
                              fpar(ftext("red text", fp_red)))

#and this creates the powerpoint slides. I redacted some names but that shouldnt affect your understanding
#as they are text names not functions etc
#begin by adding slides now that we have named all slides in template and placeholders

trial <- df %>%                                                                                                  
  add_slide(layout = "study objective", master = "rlayout")  %>%                           #new slide
  ph_with("Study Objective", location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "title")) %>%
  ph_with("Survey Global Sales - Specifically:",
          location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "center object")) %>%
  ph_with(studyobjective1, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "lower object")) %>%
  print(target = "C:/Users/mi/Desktop/R/PPT/df.pptx")    #save in new location
```

But when I print the powerpoint slide the word "specifically" isn't bolded which should be due to sudyobjective1 object containing the bold formatting. Instead I get the error in the title of this post. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example so that we can help you? Here, `df` is unknown; also could you start with the default template as we don't have yours

Comment: can you link the default template please? Thanks for the package by the way!

Comment: @DavidGohel are you open to meeting over zoom? totally understand if not.

Comment: you can use `read_pptx()` as is to start with the default template.